# Is there any way to tell when wp_postmeta has been updated?

Tags: posts, post-meta

I have a website for a client, where users can vote up or down certain things on a leaderboard. The up vote is stored within wp_postmeta as a field.

What I'd like to be able to do is see what the league table looked like at a certain date & time, but as far as I can see there is no date/time stamp within that table to show when it was last updated. Am I missing something, or is there no way of telling when that field was amended?

thanks

Rob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right the [`wp_postmeta` table](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_postmeta):

[image]

does not save any kind of time stamp. Unlike for example the `wp_posts` table with `post_date`, `post_modified` and such. So you have to implement a mechanism to keep track of the points in time when votes happened yourself.